# How do you fix favicon and manifest image issue while building Python Django Website?

Tags: python, html, django, manifest, favicon

I am fairly new to coding and I'm doing this course where they teach you to build your own portfolio website suing python django. So far, everything has been going great. Everything loads perfectly except for my images whenever I upload them to the admin. They do not show up on the main site.

Stackoverflow does not allow me to upload images yet. They only let me do a link. I'll copy both the text and the image link.

This is my settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

This is my URLs file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import jobs.views 

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', jobs.views.homepage, name='home')  
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_ROOT = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_ROOT = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is what I have in my HTML code right now.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
  {% for job in jobs.all %}

    <!-- Row 1 Box 1 
    ================== -->
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card shadow-sm">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ job.image.url }}">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"> {{ job.summary }} </p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the error messgae I get:
TypeError: serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_ROOT'

> [26/Jan/2022 03:10:17] "GET /media/images/Marketing.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 63906
> Not Found: /requestProvider.js.map
> [26/Jan/2022 03:10:17] "GET /requestProvider.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 2512
> Not Found: /docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json
> [26/Jan/2022 03:10:18] "GET
> /docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2572

[Code for this problem and the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlIyk.jpg)

[This is where the image is supposed to show but isn't showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PesIE.png)

How can I fix this issue. Let me know if you need more resources.

Comment: Can you try ````MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'```` in settings.py

Comment: Nope. Still didnt work.

 :(